# Access restriction for users that are not admin and landlord

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a laravel project. I want to restrict the api/property/create route so that only admins and landlord users can create property.However i am meeting a challenge in implementing this functionality.

Here is my route to create property

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'adminLandlord']], function() {
    Route::post('/property/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\PropertyController@create')->name('createProperty');
});
```

Below is my AccountType Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AccountType extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $name = [
        1 => 'Admin',
        2 => 'Landlord',
        3 => 'Guest',
        4 => 'Tenant',
        5 => 'Service Provider',
    ];
    const ADMIN = 1;
    const LANDLORD = 2;
    const GUEST = 3;
    const TENANT = 4;
    const SERVICEPROVIDER = 5;

    public static function getAccountName($id) {
        $name = [
            1 => 'Admin',
            2 => 'Landlord',
            3 => 'Guest',
            4 => 'Tenant',
            5 => 'Service Provider',
        ];
        return $name[$id];
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is the User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'account_type',
        'email',
        'password',
        'phone_number'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    const ADMIN = 'Admin';
    const LANDLORD = 'Landlord';
    const GUEST = 'Guest';
    const TENANT = 'Tenant';
    const SERVICEPROVIDER = 'Service Provider';

    // Get property(s) under a user
    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AccountType::class);
    }


    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->account_type == 1; // this looks for an account_type column in the users table
    }

    public function isLandlord()
    {
        return $this->account_type;

    }

    public function isGuest()
    {
        return $this->account_type;
    }

    public function isTenant()
    {
        return $this->account_type;
    }

    public function isServiceProvider()
    {
        return $this->account_type;
    }
}
```

Here is my adminLandlord middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\AccountType;

class AdminLandlordMiddleware
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    // protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    // public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    // {
    //     $this->auth = $auth;
    // }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->isLandlord($this->getAccountTypeId('Landlord')) || !Auth::user()->isAdmin($this->getAccountTypeId('Admin'))){
            // return $next($request);
            return response()->json(['error_message' => 'Unauthorized action'], 403);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    public function getAccountTypeId($name)
        {
            $accountType = AccountType::where('name', $name)->first(); 
            return $accountType->id;
        }
}
```

I need to be able to pass the getAccountTypeId() to the isAdmin and isLandlord methods so as to get the accountTypeId which i will then use in the condition in the middleware. I tried it the way shown above but its not working out.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Couldn't you use [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies)?

Comment: I am new to the framework and have not interacted with policies, however now that you have suggested it, let me attempt implementing it using policies